# Closing a modal window in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm doing an app, and i have a modal window, and i want to close the modal window when i click on the black background, and the way i did it works, the problem, is that i have white container in the center of the modal window, and i need to click stuff there, and when i do it, it closes the whole window, even though the onClick event is on the ModalHero that is the container that has the black background.

Just let me show you the code...

```
import React from "react";
import { ModalHero, ContainSettings } from "./ModalSettingsStyled";

const Modal = ({ setProfile }) => {
  return (
    <ModalHero onClick={() => setProfile(false)}>
      <ContainSettings></ContainSettings>
    </ModalHero>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

When i click on ContainSettings it closes the window, but i don't want that to happen.

Let me show you the css ( i'm using styled components )

```
import styles from "styled-components";

export const ModalHero = styles.section`

width: 100%;
height: 100vh;

background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);

position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;

display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;


`;

export const ContainSettings = styles.div`

width: 45%;
height: 40vh;

border-radius: .5rem;
background: white;

`;
```

This is how it looks

[image]

What can i do so when i click the black background it will close the window, but when i click on the white container it won't

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Don't render `ContainSettings` as a child component of your backdrop component `ModalHero`, a click event originating in `ContainSettings` is propagating to `ModalHero`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an Event.stopPropagation() `onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}` on your `ContainSettings`

```
<ContainSettings onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
```

Here a live example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-67143988-jmc0k?file=/src/Modal.js